# How to find all solutions of a given LP problem

Tags: matrices, self-learning, linear-programming

Find all the solutions of the following LP problem

maximize $z= 3x_1+x_2+0x_3$

subject to

$x_1+2x_2 \leq 5$

$x_1+x_2-x_3 \leq 2$

$7x_1 + 3x_2 -5x_3 \leq 20$

and $x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq 0$

my final LP is:

$x_3 = 3-x_2-x_4+x_5$

$x_1 = 5 - 2x_2 -x_4$

$x_6 = 0 + 6x_2+2x_4+9x_5$

$z = 15-5x_2-3x_4$

I have found a solution of this LP $(5, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0)$, but I'm not sure what it means by finding 'all the solutions', can someone give me a hint?

Comment: there's a typo for the third constraint.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh fixed it. Can you help me out with the thought process

Comment: Is it common to see $0\cdot\text{something}$ in $z= 3x_1+x_2+0x_3$?

Comment: @manooooh I'm not sure, but on the worksheet i printed out has a $0$ in front of $x_3$.

Answer (score 3):

You have found a solution, but could there be another one? can you describe all of them?

Properties of this particular question, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are bounded. $x_3$ is unbounded from above.

Also notice that $(5,0)$ is the unique solution to

$$\max 3x_1+x_2$$

subject to $$x_1+2x_2 \le 5$$

$$x_1, x_2 \ge 0$$

If we have $x_3 < 3$, then our original problem would exclude the point $(5,0,x_3)$.

Observe that the only way to attain maximum value of $15$ is to set $x_1=5, x_2=0$. We need $x_3 \ge 3$ to make it attain the value of $15$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Does that mean any point $(5, 0, x_3); x_3 \geq 3$ is a solution to this problem

Comment: I think so unless I make a mistake.